# Spring and JSP: post all options in multiselect, not only selected ones

Tags: html, jsp, spring-mvc

I've build a JSP page that contains a form with two multiple select objects and several buttons to send the elements from one to other. When the user has finished choosing the elements, clicks on a button to submit the form.
The form data is encapsulated through `commandName="mainForm"` in the JSP to a java POJO class `MainForm` that represents that form.
The problem here is that the POSTed elements from the multiselect objects are only those who  remain "selected" (in blue) when the user submits the form. Is there any clean way (without JQuery) to send all the options?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write a JS code on "onsubmit" event of form to programatically select all the options of multiselect. (Thus, making all options blue)

Like in jQuery,

```
$('#form #selectId option').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

I don't see better way of doing it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I solved the problem with a similar solution: `$(function() {
                $("#submitForm").click((function() {
                    $('#unitsIn option').each(function(i){
                        $(this).prop("selected", true);
                    });
                }));
            });`   I don't know why but the .attr method didn't work... Thank you anyway !!